# FPDF not working in creating a simple pdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm playing with FPDF library and i try this simple code:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/fpdi/FPDF/fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF{
    function Header(){
        $this->Write(6,'Dokumen ini adalah sah');
    }
}
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
$pdf->Write(8, 'A complete document imported with FPDI');
// Output the new PDF
$pdf->Output();
```

But it didn't do anything. No document or exception is popped out. If i correct, if everything is fine a document should appear. I have no idea why it's not working. Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: This code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from Header function on your PDF Class. Based on the documentation at least you have to set these variables on Header function

```
    function Header()
{
    // Select Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Framed title
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}
```

And this is my code that looks like your code, and its works

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class PDF extends FPDF{
    function Header()
{
    // Select Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    // Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    // Framed title
    $this->Cell(50,10,'Dokumen ini sah',1,0,'C');
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}

}

$pdf = new PDF();

// print_r($pdf);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
```

**Result :**
[image]

More detail you can visit official documentation of [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: oh, so i need to set the font also in the header. Thanks i'll try

Comment: If my answer solve you problem, don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: @farhan In your code, since you set the font before calling `AddPage()`, it's not necessary to set a font in `Header()`, because a font is already set.